# How can I remove a webapp in GNOME 3.2?

Tags: gnome3

I followed this blog post to install a webapp in GNOME 3.2 using Epiphany web browser.

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/gnome-3-web-application-mode/

How can I remove it after I installed the web app?

Answer (score 3):

[*Quoting from relevant answer on Ask Ubuntu:*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87954/how-to-delete-webapp-created-using-epiphany)

> 1. Open Epiphany web browser.
> 2. Type `about:applications` as URL and press Enter.
> 3. Delete the web app.